# How to take advantage of format control supplied by a subclass of simple-error

Tags: error-handling, common-lisp

I am currently developing using the [cxml-stp](http://www.lichteblau.com/cxml-stp/) framework, but while parsing I do get a [cxml-stp:stp-error](http://www.lichteblau.com/cxml-stp/doc/pages/cxml-stp__class__stp-error.html), which is a subclass of [simple-error](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw50/CLHS/Body/e_smp_er.htm), which is documented to be a kind of error where a format-control is supplied.

How can I print the error message? As neither API supplies any specific functions and a simple `FORMAT` just results in the object being printed but not using the supplied FORMAT string.

e.g.

```
(SB-KERNEL:CASE-FAILURE
 ETYPECASE
 #<CXML-STP:STP-ERROR "text includes characters that cannot be ~
                represented in XML at all: ~S"
   {1007814951}>
 (STRING SIMPLE-STRING))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply write the condition object without escaping:

```
(write condition :escape nil)
```

Comment: Or make it even more concise with PRINC

Answer (score 1):

```
(defun try-handle-error (err)
  (handler-case
      (error err)
    (serious-condition (condition)
      (apply #'format
         (nconc (list t)
            (cons (simple-condition-format-control condition)
              (simple-condition-format-arguments condition)))))))

(try-handle-error (make-condition
        'simple-error
        :format-control "say something ~s~&"
        :format-arguments '(42)))
```

This would be an example. Basically, format-control and format-arguments are slot-readers declared on simple-error class. When you handle an error, you can call them on that error to get the values it received during creation.

Comment: I tried your example str+c & str+v in sbcl resulting in: `; in: LAMBDA NIL
;     (FORMAT-ARGUMENTS CONDITION)
; 
; caught STYLE-WARNING:
;   undefined function: FORMAT-ARGUMENTS

;     (FORMAT-CONTROL CONDITION)
; 
; caught STYLE-WARNING:
;   undefined function: FORMAT-CONTROL
; 
; compilation unit finished
;   Undefined functions:
;     FORMAT-ARGUMENTS FORMAT-CONTROL
;   caught 2 STYLE-WARNING conditions`